# how to run mysql v5.5 on redhat linux

Tags: mysql, linux, path, installation, redhat

I am new to both linux and also mysql but somehow by obtaining help from net I have installed mysql v5.5 on redhat. It starts fine, I have confirmed this by running command:
"/etc/init.d/mysqld status"

But I am not able to change password using command:
mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
It gives error : bash: mysqladmin: command not found.
I tried searching mysqladmin by using command "find / -name mysqladmin" but it returned no result

All I can search on net is adding to path '/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin' but directory structure after installation mysql v5.5 has changed. There is no such directory like /usr/bin/local/mysql now.

please help me with how to run mysql after changing root's password.

Comment: Not really a question about programming, more about server administration or how-to-use-an-application. Would be better suited on superuser or serverfault.

Comment: But hint: `mysqladmin` should be installed when you install `mysql` - did you install all the necessary packages? Try your apt-get/yum/alien...

Comment: I have installed all the required packages. But still I am not able to locate mysqladmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all see what MySQL packages are installed

```
rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
```

Second, try using `locate` in order to find the tool path

BTW, 
According to [pbone](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&limit=4&srodzaj=1&dl=40&search=mysqladmin&dist%5B%5D=28&dist%5B%5D=0&field%5B%5D=1&field%5B%5D=2) mysqladmin is provided by mysql-client (rather than mysql) as it was on  older cackeages

Comment: MySQL-embedded. MySQL-client, MySQL-sever, MySQL-devel, MySQL-shared, MySQL-test. All the packages contained in .tar file are installed

Comment: I am not able to locate mysqladmin :(